# Anonymous transactions technology for a cryptocoin?

Tags: currencies, privacy, cryptography

I’m thinking of investing in a cryptocoin with anonymous transactions feature. So far there are 3 well-known technologies for that: coinjoin (Bitcoin), masternodes (Darkcoin) and CryptoNote (Bytecoin). CryptoNote looks more appealing due its innovative ring signatures technology. Can anybody explain which option would be the best and why?

Answer (score 1):

CoinJoin in Bitcoin does not provide full anonymity and Darksend feature in Darkcoin is merely an implementation of the CoinJoin specification. CryptoNote, on the other hand, allows for completely anonymous transactions through ring signatures and one-time keys. It’s also blockchain analysis resistant. If you are looking to invest in CryptoNote-based coin, Bytecoin is the one to go for. It’s been around for two years (launched in 2012). Has no premine (at least there’s no evidence for that). The developers’ team is reliable and committed. The community is growing steadily. Check out this website http://bytecoin.org/

Comment: Monero (also based on Bytecoin) has more active development in my opinion, a less ridiculous story, a less ridiculous name, and graphical wallets.